# Xamarin - IOS - CLLocationManager - Timer stops when phone goes to sleep

Tags: ios, xamarin, timer, cllocationmanager

i have an application that uses the CLLocationManager in the background. It works as expected. I am trying multiple ways to optimize the battery because it needs to provide close-to-real-time location updates. I know that when the CLLocationManager is configured to work in the background, my app wakes-up everytime a location update happens.

So i was thinking about doing something like that: when a location update arrives and my event handler is called, i process the location, stop location updates and begin a timer that will start location updates again after 15 seconds.

This works pretty good as long as the phone is not sleeping or app is in background. When the phone goes to sleep, then the timer stops. Is there a way to avoid that? i was thinking that maybe as i am stopping location updates, IOS considers that the application is not allowed anymore in background so it stops all code execution, but actually i have no clue what is happening. Does anyone have a clue?

Edit: I have tested the below solution from Michal and it works like a charm. Even if the timer elapses in 15 seconds the effect on the battery are great. My app used to consume 50% of battery in a few hours. Now it doesn't even consume 5%.

This is the sequence I use:

1. Create a LocationManager and set it to work in the background with best accuracy
2. When the first gps fix arrives, set the accuracy to 3 kilometres and start a timer which elapses in 15 seconds
3. When the timer ticks set the accuracy back to best and upload to server all the received locations.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page of Apple documentation: [pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620553-pauseslocationupdatesautomatical). It describes that you can pause the location updates and then resume it. It it still doesn't solve your problem, then there's an additional note:

> For apps that have in-use authorization, a pause to location updates
>   ends access to location changes until the app is launched again and
>   able to restart those updates. If you do not wish location updates to
>   stop entirely, consider disabling this property and changing location
>   accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers when your app moves to
>   the background. Doing so allows you to continue receiving location
>   updates in a power-friendly manner.

Maybe you can use this tip and do following:

1) Start with setting accuracy to your actual need (*NearestTenMeters*)

2) When the location update comes, process it, set the location accuracy to *ThreeKilometers*, then set a 15 minut timer after which you should change the accuracy back to NearestTenMeters

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried it already but the problem is that my app runs mostly in background. You launch it once and forget about it the rest of the day. Now i did not try the ThreeKilometers accuracy because i need to have the most accurate location possible. I cannot exceed NearestTenMeters .

Comment: Actually my real problem is battery usage.

Comment: maybe you can change between different levels of accuracy? check out my answer edit

Comment: Ohhh i see. That might do the trick. So you mean that instead of stopping location updates i just change the accuracy?

Comment: Exactly. Maybe it will work, as the note on official apple documentation encourages similar trick.

Comment: Great i will try that. If i change the accuracy do you think it will be applied immediately or does it need a restart of the CLLocationManager ?

Comment: I don't think you need to restart it, but please check it out